# Perl project review - Word counter

Tags: perl

I wrote this perl script that analizes a text and plot out a bar graph of the word occurrences during the text.

Since come mainly from Javascript and PHP, i would like to know how bad is this code and if there is room for improvement and how, any tip will be appreciated!

Thanks!

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use GD::Graph::bars;
use GD::Graph::colour;


if (!$ARGV[0]) {
    die "Error:\nPlease supply a txt file and a database of words to exclude\n";
}

my $file = $ARGV[0];
my $dbfile = $ARGV[1]; 
my $cnt = 0;
my %wordlist = ();
my @db = ();
my $threshold = 18;


binmode STDOUT,"utf8";


open (HNDL,'<:utf8', $file) || die "wrong filename";

if ($dbfile){
    open (HDB,'<:utf8', $dbfile) || die "wrong filename";
    @db = <HDB>; # load file into array
    foreach my $db (@db) {
        # remove newlines
        #$db =~ s/\n\s*//;  
        chomp($db);

    }
}

while (my $val = <HNDL>)
{
    my @val = split / /, $val; # split each space build words array

    foreach my $word (@val){
        # clean the word remove newlines
        #$word =~ s/\n\s*//;    
        chomp($word);
        # clean the word remove everything until '
        $word =~ s/^.\'//;
        # clean the word remove any nonword characters
        # $word =~ s/[^a-zA-Z_0-9]//;
        # clean the word remove dots and commas
        $word =~ s/,|\.//;

        if (length($word) < 2){
            next;
        };

        # check if the word is to be excluded
        my $exclude = 0;    
        if ($dbfile){               
            foreach my $dbword (@db) {
            # check if the string contains dbword
            # ^ check for occurence at start
            # $ check for occurence at end
            # /i case insensitive
              if ($word =~ m/^$dbword$/i){
                $exclude = 1;
                #print "Escluso: $word";
              }     
            }
        }

        if($exclude == 0) {
          # check word in the hash
            if (exists $wordlist{$word}) {
                #if present augment value by one
                $wordlist{$word}++;
            }else{
            #if not present add
                $wordlist{$word} = 1;
            }
        }else{
            # do nothing
        }   




    }
}


# Export CSV

# Print header
print ("Word,Value\n");

# print hash elements for each sorted element
for my $key ( sort { $wordlist{$a} <=> $wordlist{$b} }  keys %wordlist){

        #print "$key ---> $wordlist{$key}\n\n";
        if ($wordlist{$key} >= $threshold){
            print "$key,$wordlist{$key}\n";
            }
    }





# Export Graph
my $graph = GD::Graph::bars->new(1024, 600);

# Build data arrays
my @xdata = ();
my @ydata = ();
my @data = ();
for my $key ( sort { $wordlist{$a} <=> $wordlist{$b} }  keys %wordlist){

        #print "$key ---> $wordlist{$key}\n\n";
        if ($wordlist{$key} >= $threshold){
            push(@xdata,$key);
            push(@ydata,$wordlist{$key});
            }
    }

push (@data,\@xdata);
push (@data,\@ydata);

$graph->set(
    x_label     => 'Words',
    x_label_position => '0.5',
    y_label     => 'Number of Hits',
    title       => 'Number of Hits for Each Word',
    bar_spacing => 5,
    bar_width => 25,
    transparent  => '0',
    bgclr  => 'white'
) or warn $graph->error;

my $image = $graph->plot(\@data) or die $graph->error;

# write file to output
$file =~ s/\.[*]$//;

open(PNGOUT,">","$file.png");

binmode PNGOUT;
print PNGOUT $image->png;

close(PNGOUT);


close (HDB);
close (HNDL);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use lexical filehandles instead of typeglobs (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479741/why-is-three-argument-open-calls-with-autovivified-filehandles-a-perl-best-pract) for more about why; the biggest problem with typeglobs is that they are global in scope).

  ```
  open (my $handle,'<:utf8', $file) || die "wrong filename";
  ```
- You should close your filehandles sooner rather than waiting til the end of the program, if possible. For example, there's no reason to keep `HDB` open after its contents have been read into memory.
- Consider changing `@db` to a hash, then using `exists` to check whether a word is in the exclude list. This should be faster than looping through the array (depending on how many words are in the exclude list and how often a word will be in the list). Since case is not important, you could call `lc` or `uc` before testing.

  If you want to keep it as an array, then consider exiting the loop using `last` once the first match is found.
- You sort the keys of `%wordlist` twice using the same criteria. Consider storing the sorted list in a new variable.